# Will the eigenvalues of $A+\alpha B$ be dominated by ones of $B$ as $\alpha$ is large?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider 2 matrices $A,B$ and a scale $\alpha$. If $B$ has at least one non-zero eigenvalue and if $\lambda(B)\leq 0$, can we claim that we can choose $\alpha$ large enough such that every eigenvalue of $A+\alpha B$ is no larger than $0$?

---

My thoughts: Since the characteristic polynomial $del(\lambda I -A-\alpha B)$ is a polynomial of $\lambda$ with coefficients in term of $a_{i,j}+\alpha b_{i,j}$. As $\alpha$ becomes larger, the coefficients are dominated by $\alpha b_{i,j}$, so the solutions to the characteristic equation should be close to the ones to the $del(\lambda I-\alpha B)$.

However, I can't give a rigorous proof of it. Any insights or help is appreciated!

Comment: if $B$ is nilpotent, then $\lambda(B)=0$, so that the limit result is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I note that the limit result seems too strong.

Comment: Assume that $B$ has zero eigenvalue, $Bx = 0$ for some $x$, and $Ax = x$. Then $1$ is eigenvalue of $A + \alpha B$ for any $\alpha$.

Comment: No, this is not the case. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $\lambda(B) \leq 0$ but for every $\alpha > 0$, every eigenvalue of $A + \alpha B$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. So I see whether it holds also depends on matrix $A$.

Comment: What does the expression “$\lambda(B)\le0$” mean?

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question completely, note that by rewriting your sum as

$$C = a(\frac{1}{a} A + B)$$ you ask whether a small perturbation of $B$ will have negative eigenvalues if $B$ does. Once you write it this way, you can consult Kato's book (chapter one).

*Kato, Tosio*, A short introduction to perturbation theory for linear operators, New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XIII, 161 p. (1982). [ZBL0493.47008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0493.47008).

Comment: Can you say what the answer is instead of just writing that it can be found in the book?